# Empty Array when use random with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on an API in Node.js with the Sequelize ORM.

I make an API route to retrieve a random question, it works one time out of three but often returns an empty array. I can't find a solution in the documentation to prevent this...

```
  app.get('/:certifName/:levelName/random', async function (req, res) {
    return await Certification.findOne(
      {
        attributes: ['id', 'label'],
        include: [{
          model: CertificationLevel,
          as: "tcl",
          required: true,
          attributes: ['id', 'label', 'question_number', 'exam_duration'],
          include: [{
            attributes: ['id', 'label'],
            model: CertificationChapter,
            as: "tcc",
            required: true,
            limit: 1,
            order: [ [ Sequelize.fn('RANDOM') ] ],
            include: [{
              model: Question,
              as: "tq",
              required: true,
              include: [{
                model: QuestionChoice,
                as: "tqc",
                required: false,
                attributes: ['id', 'label_fr', 'is_answer'],
              }],
            }],
          }],
          where: { label: req.params.levelName }
        }],
        where: { label: req.params.certifName }
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (data) {
          res.send(data);
        }
        else
          res.sendStatus(204);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Error retrieving certification details"
        });
      });
  });
```

The last model :

```
module.exports =
  class CertificationLevel extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
      return super.init(
        {
          id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
          },
          label: Sequelize.STRING,
          slug: Sequelize.STRING,
          description: Sequelize.TEXT,
          question_number: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          exam_duration: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          created_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
          },
          updated_at: Sequelize.DATE,
          deleted_at: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        {
          tableName: 't_certifications_levels',
          sequelize,
          underscored: true,
          timestamps: false
        },
      );
    }

    static associate(models) {
      this.belongsTo(models.Certification, {
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false,
          name: "certification_id"
        }
      }),
        this.hasMany(models.CertificationChapter, { as:'tcc', foreignKey: 'level_id' })
        this.hasMany(models.Subscription, { as:'ts',foreignKey: 'level_id' })
    }
  }
```

And this is a SQL query generate :

```sql
SELECT "Certification".*,
       "tcl"."id" AS "tcl.id",
       "tcl"."label" AS "tcl.label",
       "tcl"."question_number" AS "tcl.question_number",
       "tcl"."exam_duration" AS "tcl.exam_duration"
FROM
  (SELECT "Certification"."id",
          "Certification"."label"
   FROM "t_certifications" AS "Certification"
   WHERE "Certification"."label" = 'ISTQB'
     AND
       (SELECT "tcl"."certification_id"
        FROM "t_certifications_levels" AS "tcl"
        WHERE ("tcl"."label" = 'Fondation'
               AND "tcl"."certification_id" = "Certification"."id")
        LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
   LIMIT 1) AS "Certification"
INNER JOIN "t_certifications_levels" AS "tcl" ON "Certification"."id" = "tcl"."certification_id"
AND "tcl"."label" = 'Fondation';
```

I don't know why I have two executing to my route?

I am a real beginner in back development...
Thank for you help

Comment: Can you show model associations and also generated SQL query?

Comment: I update the post with the new informations

Comment: I updated your post to replace SQL query with a formatted one. Please use something like `sqlformat.org` to format such SQL queries to make them much more readable.

Comment: Thank you, I use this for the next time !

Comment: The SQL query does not match the Sequelize query. Please provide the correct SQL query

Comment: I think it's good now !

Comment: Refresh your post and look again. They are still don't match. I see no `CertificationChapter` and its nested models as well